# Why is (startingBalance - endBalance) > (gasUsed * gasPrice) for an Ethereum transaction?

Tags: ethereum, truffle

I'm trying to write javascript tests in truffle framework to verify eth balance change after a transaction that moves funds.

I want to rule out the gas expense so that I can assert the balance change by an exact amount.

The following is how I'm trying to determine the amount of eth spent on gas:

```
let startingBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(me);
let tx = await contract.method.sendTransaction({from: me, gasPrice: 1});
let endBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(me);
let receipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx);
await (startingBalance - endBalance).should.be.equal(receipt.gasUsed);
```

My reasoning is that, since:

- The transaction doesn't change funds
- I explicitly set the transaction gasPrice to 1

the `receipt.gasUsed` should be equal to the balance change.

But running against testrpc, the test complained that the balance decremented slightly more than `gasUsed * gasPrice`, by about 2000.

Is there other factors that could contribute to eth balance change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startingBalance` and `endBalance` are `BigNumber` objects. Change your test to

`await (startingBalance.minus(endBalance)).should.be.equal(receipt.gasUsed);`

Comment: Thanks! That was my problem. I had to add .toNumber() because gasUsed isn't a BigNumber. It's surprising that operator-() does it differently than minus().

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer so the question can be closed.

Comment: Sorry. This is my first time asking question on SO. Took me a while to find where to "accept". :)

Answer (score 0):

I would not trust testrpc. Try running your code on testnet

Comment: Hmm. I started a local geth testnet, migrated my contracts. But when running the test, getTransactionReceipt() returned null.

At least I was able to get the transaction receipt in testrpc.

And many of my exceptional tests also failed to get the expected rejection. Very weird.